# Set keyboard as "US international with dead keys" in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

[Printscreen of keyboard setings options for english keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUrzp.png)I can't set the option US intl with dead keys in Ubuntu 22.04, under Settings>Keyboards> input sources. So now, using a US keyboard I am lost whenever trying to input an accented character, my texts in Portuguese end up full of "'e", "~a", "'c", which hurt productivity and focus. I have not experienced this trouble with Ubuntu 18.04 or earlier versions.
Since I am using an American laptop, buying a specialized keyboard with those diacritics is not an option. I have tried changing the locale and language settings of my system, but that has not changed the input sources options.

How can I have the good old, US Intl with dead keys keyboard option back?

context:
I am a touch typist since the 90's. A whole generation has learned, like me, to enter "'e" to print "é", "^e" to print "ê", "~a" to print "ã", "'c" to print "ç", and so on with several diacritics that are essential to many romance languages. Replacing them for a compose key, as is apparently the new suggested default, adds too much friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you CAN select "US International with dead keys"...

Assuming your system is set to Portuguese then open *Definições*, then select *Teclado*:

- You'll see "Fontes de Introdução" showing the currently selected keyboard layout(s).
- Now click the "+" sign to add another.
- Sequentially select "Inglês (Estados Unidos)" and then scroll down through all "English (...)" until you find **"Inglês (intern., com teclas mortas)"** under the letter "I".

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I have edited my OP, including a screenshot of the options, "Inglês (US, intl., com teclas mortas")" nor "English (US, intl., with dead keys" is not among them. My system was not installed with Portuguese locale originally because I will more often find solutions to technical problems in english then portuguese and the translations are seldom obvious or unique (where you mentioned "Fontes de Introdu'c~ao, my system shows Fontes de Entrada" maybe a Brazil/Portugal difference).

Comment: Yes, Brazilian is slightly different. That said, it changes nothing. FIRST select "English (US)" as is, no additional properties and in the next dialogue is where you find the option you want. And also such otion is already present during installation.

Comment: You are right, thank you! I must go past all the "English" options, and then more English keyboard options will appear under "Inglês (intern., com teclas mortas)".
The dead keys, however will not work in any dialog box in Firefox, including this one. I had to write this comment in Gedit and then paste it here. It did work in Vivaldi browser, though.